# Google Search Console Performance report - Total differs from Device report total

Tags: google-search-console

"Total Clicks" above the graph shows 90K clicks while under "DEVICES" the sum of three rows is 60K. Why are these statistics not equal?

Comment: One device can have multiple clicks.

Comment: So on device level clicks are counted only once?
"Clicking a search result to an outside page, returning, then clicking the same link again counts as only one click."

But Total clicks include also these?

Comment: All explanations for discrepancy are regarding for Queries: Anonymized queries etc. 
Countries report sum is equal to total
Pages report sum is equal to total
Dates report sum is equal to total

Devices seems to be 30% shy month over month